# How to call interceptor before every Dispatcher servlet in spring web flow?

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, spring-webflow-2

Hi friends   i am working session in spring web flow , before every event i want check session is exist or not for this i want call interceptor , so i have problem to  configure the interceptor in web flow here id my web flow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <faces:resources />




    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pcx.interceptor.check" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pcx.ui.converter" />
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.pcx.ui.converter.ExecuteTimeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>




    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
        <property name="defaultHandler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Maps logical view names to Facelet templates in /WEB-INF (e.g. 'search' 
        to '/WEB-INF/search.xhtml' -->
    <bean id="faceletsViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Dispatches requests mapped to org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller 
        implementations -->
    <bean id="sssssssss"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

    <!-- Dispatches requests mapped to flows to FlowHandler implementations -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: And the problem is? Although I can guess that your interceptor isn't fired. You need to set it in the `FlowHandlerMapping` by setting the `interceptors` property. The `<mvc:interceptors />` is to be used with `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: hi @M.Deinum can  you explain  sir.how ?

Comment: @M.Deinum i have configure the AOP but  how can i call interceptors sir

Comment: What is that isn't to understand about setting the `interceptors` property? Also Spring's `HandlerInterceptor`s have nothing to do with AOP so not sure where that is coming from. In short remove `<mvc:interceptors /> ` and add a `<property name="interceptors"><bean class="com.pcx.ui.converter.ExecuteTimeInterceptor"/></property>` to the `FlowHandlerMapping` bean.

Answer (score 1):

The `<mvc:interceptors />` are meant to be used with `<mvc:annotation-driven />` it doesn't work for regular configured `HandlerMapping` beans. For those you need to configure their `interceptors` property.

To solve your proble remove the `<mvc:interceptors />` and add the configuration to the `FlowHandlerMapping` bean.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <bean class="com.pcx.ui.converter.ExecuteTimeInterceptor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: but sir when in invalidate the session , how  can another user logout when its check the session

Comment: I don't understand your question/comment.

Comment: sir any idea about session (server side session) , when user lo-gin one side and another user login from same password and user name (from another machine ) ,at that time first user logout from automatically  on every when second user invalidate the first session  .

Comment: As stated that is a different question and not related to this one. Also it appears as if you are trying to invent your own security framework I strongly suggest you take a look at [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) which supports this out-of-the-box.

Comment: sir  means interceptor in wrong concept  in  for session

Comment: sir please can add me mail id(rishigautamg@gmail.com)  ,  gave the any idea or example about the spring

Comment: As stated earlier, that is a different question. Your question was about how to apply the interceptors. Now you have another question regarding security, ask another question don't use comments for that.

Comment: i try the inteceptor for invalidate the session because i have no idea how to do  this  please help me no one here tell me in my company .

Comment: sir my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138381/how-to-invalidate-the-session-in-spring-web-flow