# How to invalidate the session in spring web flow?

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

when user login one side and another user login from same password and user name (from another machine ) ,at that time first user logout from automatically on every time  when second user invalidate the first session. I am using the server side session ,   i have login flag in data base user is already login or not .any idea friends

Comment: As I suggested in the other thread take a look at Spring Security as that has support for that out-of-the-box. Don't try to reinvent the security wheel.

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you try with Spring Security Single Sign-On implementation.

This link may be useful to you http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/